# Automate execution of a command in EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a test case written in Java and as part of that test, there is a requirement to log in to an AWS EC2 instance and then execute a command (e.g ls) in an automated way. I tried using the java JSch library but it is not working with the was EC2 instance.I am getting a timeout error. Can anyone give me some pointers on how this can be done?

Comment: AWS EC2 doesn´t say much about your machine.  Is it Windows? Linux ? What distribution/version?. If is Linux you may use _cron_

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: [mcve], and how that aws instance is set up. What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Just the timeout or any other error?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your EC2 instances are [managed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/managed_instances.html) and then use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

A managed instance is any machine configured for AWS Systems Manager. Run Command allows you to automate common administrative tasks and send commands to a user-defined fleet of EC2 instances.

Comment: Thank You jarmod,Robert and nacho for pitching in. I will try it out.